# Laravel Slack Notification, starting a thread

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, slack-api

Right now I have notification classes that send slack messages whenever a new Incident, or Incident note is created. Within the application the Incident and the IncidentNote are related via I.D. in my tables of the database.

What I am trying to do is whenever a incident is created it sends a slack message to the channel but then when a note is created for the Incident it is then stored in a thread below the Incident in slack. I looked over the Laravel docs with no luck on finding if this is even possible.

How should I go about trying to attempt this?

Comment: Are you looking for posting thread and then posting comment on that thread on slack? I am doing similar thing. I create thread if new order placed and I post comment on that thread when the order will be shipped. YOu need to store each unique thread ID you get from slack into your DB record and you need to track any comment for that thread or not. For slack operation, I have create a class and i import that class on my controllers and then I track any activities on slack channel as well as any activity on my laravel application. I am doing both way action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps:** 
 - Every-time when you create new incident on slack, you will get thread id.
 - Store that thread ID into your DB corresponding to your incident record.
 - Next time when you want to post any comment or note on any specific thread on slack, post message containing thread ID from the DB.

Simply, You have to track and store thread id along with your incident. Next time generate a json message to post into a specific thread by including that thread id into your json data.

Example: to post note/comment to a specific thread on slack:

```
public function postReplyThread($msg,$ts){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                "token=".$this->access_token."&channel=".$this->channel."&text=".$msg."&ts=".$ts."&thread_ts=".$ts);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $server_output;
}
```

Where `thread_ts=".$ts` is the thread where you want your comment to be posted.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense I will give that a shot!

Comment: when you post new message on slack, that will return you `thread_ts` and you have to store that somewhere because you need this `thread_ts` when you wanna post back to that thread. actually `thread_ts` is not an ID but it works as ID when you specify the channel.

Comment: Just remember you post message to a channel and you will get thread ts. next time you pass channel as well as thread ts both. First try and if you want I can post my whole code later.

Comment: im just gathering ideas right now on how to do it, what you posted seems like it will work right, hence why I accepted it as an answer. Another way I was thinking of doing it was simply making the slack message be sent as a link that sends them back to my UI. Or I may do both, depends on what my boss wants overall too

Comment: yeah right but even you can track each and every message posted in a channel. So need to make complex. My requirement was sending bunch of commands via special messages with parameters and values. run server side activities and post back the result to slack. something like operating a software hosted in our server using slack.

Comment: I'm actually surprised this isnt documented better, it seems like something a lot of people will use. I'm sure were not the only two thinking about it.